# How to change the click area of an SVG shape so that two of them next to each other don't ovelap each other?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: Image of the two SVGs]

I have drawn a dashed line showing the boundaries of the black shape which is on top of the other shape. My problem is that where it overlaps the blue one, I want to click that blue shape and not the black one. So I want to be able to click each of them exacly where they are visible.

I have been trying to solve this for hours, but couldn't make it work.

Here is the code I have:

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -71px;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 133 67" width="133" height="67" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" pointer-events="visiblePainted">
  <path d="M66.5 1.5L1.5 66.5H131.5L66.5 1.5Z" fill="#000eee" stroke="black" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="visiblePainted" id="shape1"/>
</svg>
<svg class="rotate" viewBox="0 0 133 67" width="133" height="67" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" pointer-events="visiblePainted">
  <path d="M66.5 1.5L1.5 66.5H131.5L66.5 1.5Z" fill="currentColor" stroke="black" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="visiblePainted" id="shape2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: put both paths in the same svg element. Get the click event from the paths not from the svg

Comment: Or set the root `<svg>` nodes `pointer-events` to `none` if you don't want them to catch pointer-events.